# How is it possible to pick the last value after hash?

Tags: java

I have a String as shown below

How is it possible to pick the last value after hash ??

```
Fountain#Apple#Big(7)   should give Big(7) 
Fountain#Orange(8)      should give Orange(8)
```

I can do this using **StringTokienizer** , but just want to chek if there is any better and simple way of doing this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('#') + 1)` should do the job.

Comment: @Kiran if this is your answer please mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` method of the `String` class, like so:

```
String apples = "Fountain#Apple#Big(7)";
String[] sections = apples.split("#");
// sections[0] == "Fountain"
// sections[1] == "Apple"
// sections[2] == "Big(7)"
String lastSection = sections.length > 0 ? sections[sections.length - 1] : null;
System.out.println(lastSection); // Prints: "Big(7)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex version:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=#)([^#]*)$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String afterHash = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Over splitting and doing index math? I usually find regex solutions to be more robust because they don't suffer from off-by-one errors. It actually would be cleaner if I didn't have to handle the case where there's no hash. Care to rewrite it?

Comment: Personally, I think so, but to each his own. Given only the answer and not the problem, IMHO the splitting/substring methods and index math are much more self-documenting. But for anyone looking for a regex solution, this is it.